# Replacing the home link in woocommerce breadcrumbs

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, breadcrumbs

I know its a bit of a daft question, but like a fool I just cant find the right answer.

At the moment this is what my breadcrumbs look like

Home / Male Voice overs / Derek Doyle

I need to change the home link name to Voice Overs and link it to another page.

Please any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Woocommerce provides filters for this.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults', 'jk_change_breadcrumb_home_text' );
function jk_change_breadcrumb_home_text( $defaults ) {
    // Change the breadcrumb home text from 'Home' to 'Voice Overs'
    $defaults['home'] = 'Voice Overs';
    return $defaults;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_home_url', 'woo_custom_breadrumb_home_url' );
function woo_custom_breadrumb_home_url() {
    return 'http://yoursite.com/voice-overs';
}
```

Use these filters in your functions.php file to get the desired results.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/customise-the-woocommerce-breadcrumb/